# Efficient STFT computation

Tags: python, stft, performance

I am calculating the STFT using `scipy`, and then reducing it in size, flattening and then normalising it. Code is below. It's incredibly slow, given I'm trying to process 64,000 audio streams of about 10 seconds each. Does anyone have any suggestions on how I might speed this up?

```
f, t, Zxx = signal.stft(data, fs=sample_rate, nperseg=256)
def normalise(z):
    return np.log(np.abs(z + 1e-12)) + 1e-7

# Shrink size of STFT
avg_window = 256
a = np.zeros((Zxx.shape[0], int(Zxx.shape[1]/avg_window)))
for j, row in enumerate(Zxx):
    for i in range(int(Zxx.shape[1] / avg_window)): # note: truncated at end
        a[j][i] = np.mean(np.abs(row[i*avg_window:(i+1)*avg_window]))

flattened = np.array(Zxx).flatten() # 129 x 54
normalised = np.array([normalise(z) for z in flattened])
```

Comment: [ssqueezepy](https://github.com/OverLordGoldDragon/ssqueezepy) has the fastest STFT, and [librosa](https://github.com/librosa/librosa) fastest on single-core CPU ([benchmarks](https://github.com/OverLordGoldDragon/ssqueezepy#benchmarks)).

Comment: If I'm reading those benchmark results correctly, there doesn't seem to be all that much difference. I think my problem lies in the library calculating STFT's with too many samples along the frequency axis, and then me trying to shrink them (the middle segment of my code). Is there any way I could have the function do that? My guess is it should then be faster, as it wouldn't have to compute nearly as big a STFT, but I can't see how to do that.

Comment: Lesser `n_fft` (luckily has same effect as optimal downsampling), and greater `hop_length` (or lesser `noverlap` for `scipy`). Former shrinks freq dim, latter time.

Comment: `nfft` has to be `>=` `nperseg`, and defaults to being equal to it. So I can't reduce it any further. Even if I set `noverlap` to `0`, I still get `129x16320` points in the frequency domain, which is a *lot*; my code goes on to reduce it down to `129x127`. (Although the second (time) dim varies by input).

Comment: If you shrink it any beyond `nfft==nperseg` & `noverlap=0`, you lose information. If this is acceptable, just set `hop_length` much greater than `nperseg` (`scipy` won't let you do this, but `librosa` and `ssqueezepy` will).

Comment: I'd also recommend against `scipy.stft`; if it's anything like `scipy.cwt`, it's flawed, or has bad defaults. `librosa` is fully correct with better defaults, and `ssqueezepy` even better in some regards ([example](https://github.com/librosa/librosa/issues/1279)).

Comment: I'm using this as input to a neural net, and having 300,000+ input features is too large, so I have to take the information loss to make the problem tractable. Correctness is absolutely a reason to shift away from scipy. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: What's the equivalent parameter to `nperseg` in ssqueezepy?

Comment: For ML I recommend [scattering](https://github.com/kymatio/kymatio), vastly superior to STFT. A nice [lecture](https://youtu.be/4eyUReyIPXg), and an even better version is currently in [dev](https://github.com/kymatio/kymatio/pull/674) (it's SOTA on timeseries with limited data). -- `nperseg` is window length (best left `None` in ssqueezepy, just set `n_fft`)

Comment: I just noticed ssqueezepy won't actually permit `hop_len > win_len` since it checks to warn for invertibility via `scipy`; I'll fix this

Comment: I finally got around to getting scattering to work (I ran into a few bugs), and it's taking forever...even if I cut down to 100 inputs. I have `J=8` and `Q=12`. Not sure if those impact perf much. This constant battle with perf makes me wonder if putting the raw signal through a NN is the right approach vs developing some features by hand that are specific to my problem.

Comment: Expect dramatically worse model accuracy with raw inputs unless you have _lots_ of it. What's your data dimensionality (input length in # of samples, number of channels), how long does it take per batch, and what's the preferred speed?

Comment: I have over 500,000 samples (with 6346 output classes in the full dataset), perhaps averaging about 5 secs each. I'm working with mono channel audio. I started it with 100 samples (and 7 output classes) before my last comment, and it's still training and only at 25% accuracy. I'd like performance that will support development at minimum, but then when we get to classifying (after training), I'd like to work towards realtime classification.

Comment: I meant how many samples is 5 secs, i.e. signal sampling rate * time. This is so I can estimate the best speed you'll get.

Comment: Oh, sorry. 12,250 * 5 => 62,250

Comment: You can see in [benchmarks](https://github.com/OverLordGoldDragon/ssqueezepy) that a 160,000 long input's CWT and STFT take .04 and .07 secs on GPU, respectively, and 3 and 1.7 secs on single-threaded CPU. Scattering is even faster with `average=True` ([benchmarks](https://www.kymat.io/userguide.html#benchmarks)). All these are realtime (with small latency on CPU); is your clocked speed notably different?